# Make object not pass by reference

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference, byref

I just found out the hard way objects are passed by reference in Javascript, for example:

```
for(var layer = 0; layer < hudLayers['layers'].length; layer++){

    // Store the to-be-calculated values in this object
    var tempValues = hudLayers['layers'][layer];

    tempValues['name'] = 'test';
}
```

This will change the value in tempValues and hudLayers.
(Seems kind of obvious, but a post without a bit of code seems so naked.)

Is there a quick way around this?

Comment: You want to assign a value to `tempValues` and have it not reflected in the `hudLayers`? Why would you want that?

Comment: You really want to know? :)
`hudLayers` contains several variables of image widths and heights. It's a HUD, so it has to be drawn multiple times per second. What's in `hudLayers` is actually the "blueprint" (base the width of this image on the value of that variable, ...)

If I simply write that back to `hudLayers`the blueprint is gone and the image on screen will always stay the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an example of passing by reference (you aren't passing any parameters).
However, you're correct; assigning an object will not make a deep copy.

You can make a deep copy of an object like this:

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") return obj;
    if (obj.constructor === RegExp) return obj;

    var retVal = new obj.constructor();
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        retVal[key] = deepCopy(obj[key]);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Note that if an object's constructor has any side-effects, this code will trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pass by reference in JavaScript. Objects are accessed through references and those references are assigned or passed passed by value, just like in Java

Answer (score -1):

Making a deep copy of an object is as simple as `objCopy = obj.toSource();`.

[.toSource on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource)

Comment: I think `toSource` returns a string representation. Could set up a test case?